# Kernel Panic, how can I fix this?

Tags: kernel, kernel-panic

I changed a setting in GRUB to fix a docker issue, next thing I know I reset my server, and here comes a week of headache. I thought I could post my question in here and get any help.
[image: Boot]

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Which setting did you change?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Can't you read his mind? Never heard of telepathy? ;-)

Comment: @Misha your kernel cannot find the rootfs, maybe your software RAID has a malfunction.

Comment: Also, how would 'a setting in grub' have any effect on a docker issue? I'm smelling XY problem.